# Change color of the textview while comparing with a string which is in array

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, textview

Here daysofInterest as ["Tuesday","Thursday","Friday","Friday"] like this,I am splitting that string by **","** using daysArray, and checking the with that array but I am not getting the result as I want, please can you fix it. and getting daysArray like this `[Ljava.lang.String;@e856c3b`

```
       String daysOfInterest=map.get("daysOfinterest");
       Log.d("DAYS OF INTEREST",daysOfInterest);
       String[] daysArray = daysOfInterest.split(",");
        Log.d("DAYS",daysArray.toString());
        for(int i=0;i<daysArray.length;i++){
            if(daysArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("sunday")){
                tvSunday.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(ActivitySavedCareAlerts.this,R.drawable.style_circle_filled_green));
                tvSunday.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.white));
            }
            if(daysArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("monday")){
                tvMonday.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(ActivitySavedCareAlerts.this,R.drawable.style_circle_filled_green));
                tvMonday.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.white));
            }
            if(daysArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("tuesday")){
                tvTuesday.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(ActivitySavedCareAlerts.this,R.drawable.style_circle_filled_green));
                tvTuesday.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.white));
            }
            if(daysArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("wednesday")){
                tvWednesDay.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(ActivitySavedCareAlerts.this,R.drawable.style_circle_filled_green));
                tvWednesDay.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.white));
            }
            if(daysArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("thursday")){
                tvThursday.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(ActivitySavedCareAlerts.this,R.drawable.style_circle_filled_green));
                tvThursday.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.white));
            }
            if(daysArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("friday")){
                tvFriday.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(ActivitySavedCareAlerts.this,R.drawable.style_circle_filled_green));
                tvFriday.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.white));
            }
            if(daysArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("saturday")){
                tvSaturday.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(ActivitySavedCareAlerts.this,R.drawable.style_circle_filled_green));
                tvSaturday.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(),R.color.white));

            }
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: use else if and not only if

Comment: there are two mistakes

Comment: please can you show my mistakes?

Comment: have you tried what i said

Answer (score 0):

there are two mistakes

1)You are not breaking the loop anywhere. so it will go from i=o to i=length everytime and value assigned to color will be last value. return from if statment

2)in setClorText Method you are using white as parameter. try different colors if you want to change colors